# how to connect bootstrap modal with sigma.bind event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sigma.js, linkurious

I want to show modal when a node is clicked, but I couldn't know how to pass data to the modal, and how to show the modal.

all the examples I found, the modal is shown after a button is clicked etc,

[HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_js&stacked=h):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>

        </script>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    // Generate graph:
    // Instantiate sigma:
    // binding sima instance to an event
    s.bind('doubleClickNode ', function(e) {
        var id = e.data.node.neo4j_data['ID'];
        $('#MyModal').append('<p class="navbar-text">ID: '+ id +'</p>');
        $("#MyModal").modal();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this good enough solution

```
        s.bind('doubleClickNode ', function(e) {
            console.log("node is clicked!");
            var id = e.data.node.neo4j_data['ID'];
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

            $('#my_label').html ( id ); // my_label inside modal
            $('#myModal').modal('show')            

        });
```